# Call of function without prototype error message with Delay1TCYx (1) ( C language )

Tags: c, pic

We have a project that were running using C and a PICkit 3. Our issu is that we remain getting the same error message and arent sure whta the issue is. Any help / advice would be great.

```
void main (void)
{
    ANSEL = 0;  //turn off all other analog inputs
    ANSELH = 0;
    ANSELbits.ANS0 = 1; // turn on RA0 analog
    ADCON0 = 1; // justify right

    ADC_Init();                  // Call ADC_Init function
    ADC_Convert();
    Delay1TCYx(1);           //delay 1 x 1 cycles 
    int reading0 = ADRESL + (ADRESH * 256); //convert result to 10 bits
    
    if (reading0 = 0b1000000011)
    {   
        readingsamples();
    }
while(1);
}
```

Comment: Where  is the prototype for `Delay1TCYx`?

Comment: we have ''' #include <delays.h> ''' further up in the code

Comment: And?  The error message is telling you that there is no in-scope prototype for function `Delay1TCYx()`.  Possibly you have misspelled the function name.  Possibly it is not declared because of the particular compilation circumstances (for example, macros that are / are not declared).  Possibly you are getting the wrong `delays.h`.  Possibly it isn't provided at all.  We can tell you something about what the diagnostic means, but we do not have enough information to explain with any confidence why it is being reported.

Comment: Ill have a look at it. What further info do you need?

Comment: What is the error message, what does the prototype for Delay1TCYx look like (if that is the error you are getting).